# JQuery Sortable Plugin and Telerik RadGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, telerik, radgrid

Has anyone combined the Telerik RadGrid with the JQuery sortable plugin for reordering the rows?  At first glance, it works great.  However, I'm not actually doing development so I was wondering if anybody has tried this, any tips you could give me.  I was planning on, when the page unloads, writing the new indexes of the rows to a hidden field to change the ordering on the server.

Any advice would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: I haven't so I'll just comment. Is there no way to use the build in sorting on the [RadGrid](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/generalfeatures/sorting/defaultcs.aspx)? you would use the `GridSortCommandEventArgs` with a RadAjax postback.

Comment: But sortable doesn't require a postback, and what I'm trying to do is give the user the ability to prioritize the data in the grid, so no, sorting doesn't quite give us custom ordering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery sortable plugin would work if no detail table is provided; with a detail table, it becomes harder to implement.  I scrapped it temporarily, I may try to implement at a later point.

Answer (score 0):

The RadGrid currently supports [multicolumn sorting](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grdmulticolumnsorting.html).  What would jQuery provide you over and above Telerik?

Comment: Row sorting.  I'm looking for ordering the rows... I can reorder the rows to adjust the importance of certain records, keep track of the changes, then store them in a hidden field.

Comment: Have not used jQuery plugin for rows reorder, but I know that the telerik ajax grid has built-in row drag and drop  -http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/programming/draganddrop/defaultcs.aspx